# How do I make my Type:Time to work with my Line Chart?

Tags: chart.js

I am working on creating a Line graph that plots points at different times during one day for different days and in order to do that, I need to use the type: time on the xAxes. I have the moment.js downloaded, but the type:time is  giving me an error. Without the type:time, the X axis label is too long and makes the graph look bad. Any ideas what I would need to do to fix this?

I have tried to put the data points this way:
data: [ {x: newDate(2019, 06, 24, 08, 00), y: 24}]
but it still didn't work with the type:time

```
<canvas id="timechart" width="800" height="400"  role="img"></canvas>
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('timechart');
    var timeFormat = 'MM/DD/YY HH:mm';
    function newDate(days) {
        return moment().add(days).toDate();
    }
    function newDateString(days) {
        return moment().add(days).format();
    }
    var timechart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "line",
        data: {
            labels: [newDate(0), newDate(1), newDate(2), newDate(3), 
newDate(4), newDate(5), newDate(6), newDate(7), newDate(8), newDate(9), 
newDate(10), newDate(11),
            newDate(12), newDate(13), newDate(14), newDate(15), 
newDate(16), newDate(17)],
            datasets: [
                {
                    data: [12, 21, 32, 25, 16, 14, 7, 25, 18, 20, 22, 15, 
17, 11, 19, 28, 30, 10],
                    label: 'D Speed',
                    fill: false,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(102, 147, 188, 1)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(102, 147, 188, 1)',
                    radius: 4,
                    hoverRadius: 5,
                }, {
                    data: [8, 16, 24, 30, 20, 10, 12, 21, 32, 15, 17, 11, 
22, 18, 29, 17, 8],
                    label: 'U Speed',
                    fill: false,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 147, 44, 1)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(255, 147, 44, 1)',
                    radius: 4,
                    hoverRadius: 5,
                }
            ],
        },
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true,
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    type: 'time',
                }],
                yAxis: [{
                    display: true,
                }]
            },

        }
    });

</script>
```

I expect the x axis labels to show just the MM/DD/YY HH:MM but it is actually not showing the chart at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you shared worked for me. Make sure that you've included Moment and the non-bundled version of Chart.js in your project. E.g.:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.24.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
```

Also, check your browser's developer console to see if there are any JavaScript errors that can help give more clues as to the problem. You can access in Chrome by hitting F12.